# Parse Adf.ly URL using PHP

Tags: php, parse-url

I have a link like that:
`http://adf.ly/2323070/http://www.fileflyer.com/view/O33TOYUAFMIFF`

And I want to get only this part of the URL:
`http://www.fileflyer.com/view/O33TOYUAFMIFF`

**Note**
The URL number can be change, so the syntax of the URL is:
`http://adf.ly/{NUMBERS}/{URL}`

How can I parse this URL?

Thanks!
and sorry for my English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple regex of `#https?://(www\.)?adf\.ly/\d+/(.*)#i` should do the trick. This also supports https://adf.ly` (in case it exists) and http://www.adf.ly.

```
<?php
    $url = "http://‌‌‌‌‌‌"."adf.ly/2323070/http://www.fileflyer.com/view/O33TOYUAFMIFF";
    preg_match("#https?://(www\.)?adf\.ly/\d+/(.*)#i", $url, $matches);
    var_dump($matches[2]);
?>
```

outputs

`string(43) "http://www.fileflyer.com/view/O33TOYUAFMIFF"`

Answer (score 0):

A regexp like `#http://adf.ly/(\d+)/(.*)#i` should do the trick. For example:

```
<?php
$theinput = 'http://adf.ly/2323070/http://www.fileflyer.com/view/O33TOYUAFMIFF';
$regexp = '#http://adf.ly/(\d+)/(.*)#i';
if (preg_match($regexp, $theinput, $matches)) {
    echo "Number: " . $matches[1] . "<br>\n";
    echo "URL: " . $matches[2] . "<br>\n";
}
else {
    echo "No match!";
}
```